# C# Flickering during animation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms project about animating the movement of rectangles but all animations are accompanied by some amount of flickering mostly from the border of the drawn rectangle. I have already turned on double buffering for the form and while it helped it didn't solve my issue. Is there anything I can do code-wise to fix it? Below is the fragment of my code that deals with drawing the rectangles. I have left out the code that provides the rectangles to draw and replaced with a summary as I don't think it pertains to my question. This is all done in a method that is passed an instance of the form it draws on (DrawForm), a Graphics object(g), a Pen object(pen) and a Brush object (brush).

```
   for(int i = 0; i < animation_frames; i++)
   { 
       for(int b = 0; b < objects.Count; b++)
       { 
         /*Summary: Checks what each object is doing for this frame. Populates a RectangleF array
         called recs with rectangles corresponding to the objects' new positions.
         */
       }
       DrawForm.Refresh();
       g.FillRectangles(brush, recs);
       g.DrawRectangles(pen,recs);
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);   
     
 
   }
```

Comment: Well the Refresh will enforce flickering. Where exactly does the Graphics object come from? It should come from the e.Graphics parm of a Paint event. Do not try to cache it. For an animation use a Timer and in the Tick call Invalidate to trigger the Paint event. Don#t use Sleep.

Comment: _Invalidate and Update_ Well that is not what I suggested!! - If you want your graphics to persist (do you?) you are doing it all wrong. _The graphics object comes from the form._ Show the code! I hope you don't use CreateGraphics. We do not see nearly enough of the relevant code. - Btw: Winforms is no good at drawing smooth animations for several reasons..

Comment: Moving the two lines that draw stuff to the paint event fixed it.

Comment: The transition from clearing everything drawn to drawing new stuff must have been what was causing the issue. Letting the paint event handle both the removing of objects drawn from the previous frame and drawing the new ones eliminated the flickering

Comment: Glad you got it working..